# How to write prompt to set default select option

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select

I want to display default select option as "select Size" here. How to give it this select option?

Any help is appreciated.

This is my slim file:

```
= select_tag "standard_size_id", 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@standard_sizes, "id", "name"), include_blank: true, class: 'form-control'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way  just add `prompt` attribute and remove `include_blank`

```
<%= select_tag "standard_size_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@standard_sizes, "id", "name"), class: 'form-control', prompt: 'Select Size' %>
```